# viewcontroller not found in appdelegate.m file

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I am following the ios tutorial to incorporate Facebook into my app. Everything went fine until I got to the part about adding a logout button. I keep getting an error stating property "ViewController" not found on object of type. What am I doing wrong? Here is the code from my appdelegate.m file.

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Add the requests dialog button
    UIButton *requestDialogButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    requestDialogButton.frame = CGRectMake(40, 150, 200, 40);
    [requestDialogButton setTitle:@"Send Request" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [requestDialogButton addTarget:self 
                            action:@selector(requestDialogButtonClicked)
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.viewController.view addSubview:requestDialogButton];
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Have you declared `viewController` of type `UIViewController` in your header, and synthesized? It also looks like you are doing work in your `AppDelegate` which I would advise against. You should implement this in your `viewcontrollers' viewDidLoad:` or `viewWillAppear:` methods.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having the same issue, and I believe I know how to fix it. I believe that you created your test project with a storyboard? When you create a project with a storyboard, the appDelegate doesn't contain a viewController... as the storyboard will handle that.

Recreate the project and uncheck the StoryBoard check box... also the Automatic Reference Counting...

Regards,
Ezfrag